UPDATE To Value found with LIKE Command Search with Wildcards
In SSMS my search query is
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE FIELD LIKE '%AAA [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
  AND FIELD2 IN ('VALUE2', 'VALUE3', 'VALUE4')

I need my update statement to set the column to the found value.
Say a match is found and the found value is 'AAA 1234', how do I get my update statement to set the column to that found string for the whole query result set of found matches?
Have not tried anything yet in terms of REPLACE commands or anything similar.
I need my update statement to be:
UPDATE TABLE
SET FIELD2 = 'EXACT STRING FOUND IN WILD CARD SEARCH' (EX. 'AAA 1234')
WHERE FIELD LIKE '%AAA [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
  AND FIELD2 IN ('VALUE2', 'VALUE3', 'VALUE4')


I don't understand what you want to do.  Can you give an example of the data before and after your query

Say a match is found and the found value is 'AAA 1234', how do I get my update statement to set the column to that found string for the whole query result set of found matches? this isn't clear.

How do I set a field to a found string when the search string uses a wild card? I want to set the field to the Found String where it could be different through out the result set.

I think you want the: PATINDEX function which finds a start match of the pattern together with a SUBSTRING which takes the string portion. Note that if you have multiple wildcards in the middle of your search this gets complicated, because you don't know when your pattern actually ends :) Also, please take backups of your data before starting working on this, because it sounds like you're gonna need it

Please read [mre] and Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Determined what I am asking is not possible, as I will need to parse out the string to set a field to it. I will instead create a temp table of all possible string matches based on this clause:
'%AAA [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'

I will then inner join to the Field using a like command and set the Field2 to the match.
